# Kubernetes POD Command and argument

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning kubernetes and have the following question related to command and argument syntax for POD.

Are there any specific syntax that we need to follow to write a shell script kind of code in the arguments of a POD? For example

In the following code, how will I know that the while true need to end with a semicolon ; why there is no semi colon after do but after If etc

```
   while true;
  do
  echo $i;
  if [ $i -eq 5 ];
  then
    echo "Exiting out";
    break;
  fi;
      i=$((i+1));
      sleep "1";
  done
```

We don't write shell script in the similar way from semicolon prespective so why do we have to do this in POD.

I tried the command in /bin/bash format as well

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: bash
  name: bash
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    args:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - >
       for i in 1 2 3 4 5
       do
         echo "Welcome $i times"
       done
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Error with new code

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: `  echo "Welcome $i times"'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kubernetes and its commands or argument. Its is the way bash script is written, Eg: `while true; do date; sleep 1; done` . Notice there is no semicolon after `do`.

Comment: Also, IMO it's best to supply any multi-line script via config-maps not directly through the pod's command.

Comment: @P.... my reference to kube was because of pod where I am writing the script. So what I understood from your explanation is the syntax that I am using is because of the type of shell I am using like /bash Vs /sh ?

Comment: yes, the syntax of shell script is defined by type of shell used.

Comment: @P....  Following is the bash syntax I have now but it still error out

    args:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - >
      for i in 1 2 3 4 5
      do
        echo "Welcome $i times"
      done

/bin/bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
/bin/bash: -c: line 2: `  echo "Welcome $i times"'

Comment: can you add error on the question for proper formatting ?

Comment: @P.... I have updated the question with new syntax and error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Are there any specific syntax that we need to follow to write a shell script kind of code in the arguments of a POD?`

No, shell syntax is the same across.

`...how will I know that the while true need to end with a semicolon`

Used `|` for your text block to be treated like an ordinary shell script:

```
...
args:
- /bin/bash
- -c
- |
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5
  do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
  done
```

When you use `>` your text block is merge into a single line where newline is replaced with white space. Your command become invalid in such case. If you want your command to be a single line, then write them with `;` like you would in ordinary terminal. This is shell scripting standard and is not K8s specific.

If you must use `>`, you need to either add empty line or indented the next line correctly:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: bash
  name: bash
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    args:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - >
      for i in 1 2 3 4 5
        do
          echo "Welcome $i times"
        done
  restartPolicy: Never
```

`kubectl logs bash` to see the 5 echos and `kubectl delete pod bash` to clean-up.